# Contacting Transmission daemon through chrome extension - CORS issue?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension, transmission-daemon

I am trying to write a simple chrome extension that contact my Transmission daemon. I wrote a simple jQuery code that sends http POST to my server, but I got denied:

```
 XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://79.182.210.103:9091/transmission/rpc. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'chrome-extension://fjdfpjhmdeljfaipicgfjijiiakmmgmf' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401.
```

How can I overcome that? Can I configure Transmission daemon (running on OpenElec) to allow this, or is there any other workaround?

Answer (score 1):

Add your domain to the `permissions` array in the `manifest.json`: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declare_permissions